# Is a templated type method that returns true a good candidate to be optimised in a conditional?

Tags: c++, templates, optimization, compiler-optimization

Given these two:

```
struct Checker1 {
    bool check( Bar& bar ) {
        return true;
    }
};

struct Checker2 {
    bool check( Bar& bar ) {
        return complex_check(bar);
    }
};
```

Would this check be a good candidate to be optimised by the compiler?

```
template <typename Checker>
class Gargle {
private:
    Checker checker;

public:
    void foo(Bar bar) {
        if( checker.check(bar) ) { // this one
            // do something
        }
    }
};
```

I think it should, but not sure about it. I use `gcc` and `clang` mostly.

Comment: Not really sure what complex_check does, however: If you instantiate Gargle<Checker1>, the optimizer is likely to realize you've used a constant expression, emitting virtually no code before 'this one do something'. In the other case, it is likely to inline the result to a call to complex_check. clang has been much better at this than gcc for a while, though I've not compared lately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Checker1`, every compiler will inline the `check()` function and propagate the constant `true` into the `if()` statement and eliminate that entirely. For `Checker2` it depends on the code size of `complex_check()`.

But in C++14 you can guarantee full inlining in `constexpr` contexts. E.g. you can write

```
struct Bar {
    constexpr Bar() {}    
};

struct Checker1 {
    constexpr Checker1() {}
    constexpr bool check( Bar const& bar ) const {
        return true;
    }
};

constexpr bool complex_check(Bar const&) { return true; }

struct Checker2 {
    constexpr Checker2() {}
    constexpr bool check( Bar const& bar ) const {
        return complex_check(bar);
    }
};

template <typename Checker>
class Gargle {
private:
    Checker checker;

public:
    constexpr Gargle(Checker const& c): checker{c} {}

    constexpr int foo(Bar bar) const {
        if( checker.check(bar) ) { // this one
            // do something
        }
        return 42;
    }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr Checker2 check2;
    constexpr Gargle<Checker2> gargle{check2};
    constexpr Bar bar;
    constexpr int answer = gargle.foo(bar); // everything inline and done at compile-time
    static_assert(answer == 42, "");
}
```

and have the entire computation done at compile-time. [**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/da36a737fbd65d07) (requires gcc 5.1 or Clang 3.4)